# Getting Error while decoding the json in swift, failing while decoding

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to decode this json but it keep failing on "failed to decode" line. I validated the json, checked the struct, these looks fine to me. Am i misssing something?

**JsonManager.swift**

```
extension Bundle {
    func decode (_ file: String) -> Cities {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle")
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("failed to load \(file) bundle")
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(Cities.self, from: data) else {
             fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle")
// (Run time error here) Fatal error: Failed to decode cities.json from bundle
        }
        print("loaded")
        return loaded
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
var cities = Bundle.main.decode("cities.json")
```

**cities.json**

```
{
  "city": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Mumbai",
      "state": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Delhi",
      "state": "Delhi"
    }
]
}
```

**JsonStruct.swift**

```
struct Cities: Codable {
    struct City: Codable {
        let id: String
        let name: String
        let state: String
    }
    let city: [City]
}
```

Comment: Adding your structs would help us tell if there is a problem with them.  You should also `try` not `try?` so you get a proper error  out which will tell you the problem in more detail.

Comment: ok i'll fix the try and here is the struct

Comment: struct Cities: Codable {
    struct City: Codable {
        let id: String
        let name: String
        let state: String
    }
    let city: [City]
}

Comment: added the struct in the question as well, I forgot to add that thanks for letting me know

Comment: It all decodes fine for me.

Comment: Either use a `do`/`try`/`catch` and at minima print the thrown error, or use `try!` (app will crash), and read the console. But never use `try?` fi you don't know how to debug. And share the error output

Comment: You have to add the `cities.json` file to your Xcode Project.
 Right mouse click on the left panel in Xcode, select `Add Files to...`
 and select your `cities.json` file. Your code will then work, as it does for me.